# Attempting to Start Prefect Server in Docker Container

Tags: docker, prefect

I'm relatively new to Docker and Prefect, and I'm trying to start Prefect Server in a docker container.
Here's my Dockerfile...

```
FROM docker:dind

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make cargo && \
    python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade && \
    pip3 install docker-compose prefect && \
    prefect backend server

CMD [ "sh", "script.sh" ]
```

and here's script.sh...

```
dockerd &
prefect server start
```

after an ungodly long build, docker seems to start fine when I run `docker run --privileged=true --name prefect-server-container prefect-server-image`, but then I get a socket timeout error...
full stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa348e36a0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa348e36a0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa348e36a0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ffa348e36a0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
Exception caught; killing services (press ctrl-C to force)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f87fae1c2b0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f87fae1c2b0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f87fae1c2b0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f87fae1c2b0>, 'Connection to docker timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/cli/server.py", line 621, in start
    subprocess.check_call(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker-compose', 'pull']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/prefect", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/cli/server.py", line 662, in start
    subprocess.check_output(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker-compose', 'down']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should almost never use the `docker:dind` image; what led you to start from this as a base for your application?  Is it a C, Rust, or Python application?  (If it's a wrapper that runs `docker-compose`, you probably need to run it from the host and not inside a container itself.)

Answer (score 1):

Prefect provides its own base images on DockerHub under the name *prefecthq*. Try using the image provided here: https://hub.docker.com/r/prefecthq/server

Comment: Is there a good documentation link about this?  I want to run prefect locally for testing, in a container rather than with `pip install` in virtual environment.

Comment: Try the Core image instead: https://hub.docker.com/r/prefecthq/prefect Then have a look at https://docs.prefect.io

Comment: A bit unrelated but is there any way to instigate 3rd party package installations where the Prefect Workers can access it for import, after initiating everything? For example, if I build / start everything and then learn I missed a dependency for matplotlib, how can I install the library after the fact? I am using the prefecthq/prefect image. (I am very new to docker, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Prefect uses docker-compose underneath and requires root privileges. Hence you need to add your user to docker group.

```
$sudo groupadd docker
$sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
$newgrp docker
```

Check this link https://medium.com/@faizanzahid09/how-to-setup-a-prefect-server-916aaad27bc4